# UIWebView not showing content in arabic

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, nslocalizedstring, arabic-support

I tried to show the Arabic content in UIWebView. but getting an error as in screenshot shows.
so how to solve it
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this meta tag
 `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">`
This must solve your problem.

Comment: where to call this tag?